# How to create group on drag drop

Tags: d3.js

I want to clone and create a group element on drag drop. A rectangle will be appended to group on `dragend`.

I am able to create group with rectangle appended on drop but its getting dislocated on drop. I guess its problem with its coordinates:

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/hv2v4uLj/

Code:

```
var rectDrag = d3.behavior.drag()
                        .origin(function ()
                        {
                            var t = d3.select(this);
                            return {x: t.attr("x"), y: t.attr("y")};
                        })

                        .on('dragend', function (d)
                        {   
                            var translate = d3.transform(this.getAttribute("transform")).translate;
                            var x = translate[0];
                            var y = translate[1];
                            //Append new element
                            var newRect = d3.select("g").append("rect")
                                    .classed("drg", true)
                                    .attr("width", 51)
                                    .attr("height", 41)
                                    .attr("x", x)
                                    .attr("y", y)
                                    .style("fill", "white")
                                    .style("stroke-width", 2)
                                    .style("stroke", "#CDB483");
                        });
                rectGroup.call(rectDrag);
```

Comment: Seems like dragging behavior is missed....

Comment: @saikiran.vsk you mean drag function?

Comment: In your code we can see origin and dragend, but what about on dragging?? Observe the code for dragging http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/6123708

Comment: @saiKiran.vsk Tried this: `.on('drag', function (d)
                        {
                            translate = d3.transform(this.getAttribute("transform")).translate;
                               var x = d3.event.dx + translate[0]
                               var y = d3.event.dy + translate[1];
                        })` Still not working

Answer (score 0):

I've added code to drag event,

```
.on("drag", dragged)
```

in rectDrag at line number 22,
and the code for dragged is below

```
function dragged() {
  d3.select(this).attr("x", d3.event.x).attr("y", d3.event.y);
}
```

The updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hv2v4uLj/2/)

Hope this is what you are looking for...If not ask for more.

Comment: I think you misread my question. i was talking about drag on group (not rect element) if you see the code in question.

Comment: I already know how to drag elements. Dragging group is a bit tricky.

Comment: So, you want to create a group of what...??

Comment: Group of rectangle. I mean rectangle will be appended to the group on drag drop. After appending that rectangle, I should be able to move it around

Comment: I need a clone on drag but not move group itself. Have a look at this:http://jsfiddle.net/66b9kg5b/  I was able to create the clone on drag but scale is getting resized on move